# ORDER BY grouped fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table with a column `sector`. I have 5 sector types : 1, 1&2, 2, 3 and unknown.
I need to get results set order by sector with at the top : sector 1, 1&2,unknown (mixed), and then sector 2, and finally sector 3.

Is it possible to do that directly in SQL or do I have to handle it with PHP?

**Example**

```
| **sector** |
|     1      |
|  unknown   |
|     2      |
|    1&2     |
|     3      |
|     1      |
```

The needed result is :

```
sector 1&2
sector 1
sector unknown
sector 1
sector 2
sector 3
```

Comment: I have tried ORDER BY FIELD(sector, '1', '1&2', 'unknown', '2', '3'), it works fine but i need the first group (sector 1, 1&2 and unknown) to be mixed. For example, sector 1 can randomly come after unknown or 1&2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**FIELD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
ORDER BY FIELD(sector, '1&2', '1', 'unknown', '2', '3')
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN sector IN ('1&2', '1', 'unknown') THEN 1 
              WHEN sector = '2' THEN 2 
              WHEN sector = '3' THEN 3 ELSE 4 
         END
```

Comment: I'm actually using field exactly as you mentioned it. It works fine, but i need to have the first group (sector 1, 1&2 and unknown) mixed. For example, sector 1&2 can randomly come before sector 1 or after unknown.

Comment: @user2733521 Add sample input data and desired output. And Be specific what you want

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
order by case
 when sector=1 then 0
 when sector='1&2' then 1
 when sector='unknown' then 1.5
 when sector=2 then 2
 when sector=3 then 3
 end
```

It is possible to you have to add this virtual field to the selected fields with an alias, and you have to use the alias in the order by.

Comment: It's a bit odd to see the same field compared to both strings and numbers like that. In this situation you should really have all the options quoted. - You could also use the shorter version of the syntax here, since these are all simple comparisons. `CASE sector WHEN '1' THEN 0 ...`